# Plotting the PDF of numpy arrays using functions in Seaborn

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, seaborn

I have two numpy arrays and I want to plot the PDF of both these arrays and compare them.

```
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

error = np.array([1,2,2,3,4,4,5])
error2 = np.array([3,3,4,4,4,6])
sns.distplot(error, hist=False, rug=True,color='blue')
sns.distplot(error2, hist=False,rug=True,color='red')
plt.show()
```

[image]

This is what I did. However, the function *distplot* from seaborn is going to be deprecated and I was not sure how I would use the other functions from seaborn such as *kdeplot*, *displot* to do the same. Could anybody help me with this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `kdeplot` like this:

```
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

error = np.array([1,2,2,3,4,4,5])
error2 = np.array([3,3,4,4,4,6])
sns.kdeplot(error, color='blue')
sns.kdeplot(error2, color='red')
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. How do I label the plots? I tried sns.kdeplot(error, color='blue', label='error')
sns.kdeplot(errorf, color='red', label='error2') but it doesn't seem to function.

Comment: @G3guru I suspect that you'll need the `legend()` function from matplotlib: https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.legend.html